# Microsoft Access -> Distinct Count with inner Join and multiple selects

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, distinct

I've attempted a few iterations of this query and keep getting syntax errors. I tried making it a subquery at one point but with the inner join it was coming up with additional syntax errors. Any advice would be super appreciated.

I'm try to pull the contacts per staff member.

```
SELECT Stafflist.Staff, Count(distinct Contact) as count
FROM Contacts INNER JOIN
     StaffList
     ON Contacts.ID = Stafflist.ID
WHERE ((Contacts.Date) Between #1/1/2020# And #1/5/2020#) AND Contacts.status='Finished')
GROUP BY Staff,
ORDER BY Staff;
```

Comment: Can you give us the error message ? Have you try to remove ',' after 'Staff' in 'GROUP BY' line ?

Answer (score 2):

MS Access doesn't support `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  But you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT Stafflist.Staff, Count(Contct) as count
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Stafflist.Staff, Contacts.Contact
      FROM Contacts INNER JOIN
           StaffList
           ON Contacts.ID = Stafflist.ID
      WHERE Contacts.Date Between #1/1/2020# And #1/5/2020# AND
            Contacts.status = 'Finished'
     ) as SC
GROUP BY Staff,
ORDER BY Staff;
```